# WEKA & MySQL Setup a connection

Tags: mysql, connection, weka

WEKA Explorer can't open a connection to MySQL.

**connecting to: jdbc:mysql://MYSERVER:3306/NAME = true**

by the way: mysql driver was downloaded
mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin & 
classpath was set.

(User & Pass are ok because it works with MySQL Workbench)

when clicking on the JButton OK (in the form 'Open DB'), then a message box shows an error
- see image:

[image: Error Message]

(screen shot shows infamous "no driver" error)

weka version is 3.6.3.

any suggestions ?

Comment: this is a real stomper. I tried even modifying RunWeka.bat and still no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wasted half an hour on this same problem, here's the answer:

Download the connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Extract the JAR file.

Edit `C:\Program Files\Weka-3-6\RunWeka.ini`

Change last line to:

```
cp=%CLASSPATH%;c:/mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar
```

You may of course save your mysql-connector jar to a different path, but mind the **forward slash**, nevermind being on Windows.

Comment: How to add this CLASSPATH in linux

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem along the day. The solution took me hours. **If you are in ubuntu or debian-based linux**, first install `mysql-connector-java` with:

```
sudo apt install libmysql-java
```

It will install mysql-connector-java-* links in `/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Path to weka.jar
CP=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/:/usr/share/java/weka.jar:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
# start Explorer
java -cp $CP -Xmx500m weka.gui.GUIChooser
```

I replaced `/usr/bin/weka` with the script above. Maybe could save hours for people like me. Another option is edit your desktop menu with:

java -cp "/usr/share/java/mysql.jar:/usr/share/java/weka.jar" -Xmx500m weka.gui.GUIChooser

(in my case mysql.jar links the correct version of the driver)

Answer (score 1):

After you're done with CLASSPATH variable, You might need to create a "DatabaseUtlils.props" file and add following line in it,

*jdbcDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver*

and import it in Weka under "switch database setup"

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Actually and  can extract the source jar and import into eclipse maven and add the Mysql dependency in the pom.xml , than run maven build with parameters "clean install" , once it is finished you will have alot of errors you can ignore them those are JUnit testing and than run project as  a Java Application and use the GUI class "weka.gui.GUIChooser" add the connection string and smooth sailing.

> pom.xml add:
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>   <version>5.1.36</version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> > After maven install in complete. ![enter image description here][5] Click the explorer and Add your connection string , username and
> >     password jdbc:mysql://ip:port/databasename ![enter image description

Comment: I had  snap shots of step by step but , i dont have enough rep , also this will help developers add on 2 birds with one stone