# Weka 3.7 and 3.6 / No suitable driver found for

Tags: java, mysql

There seems to be several postings about using Weka as an implementation for programs, but there are only few seem to be related to using Weka 3.7/3.6 with a database for data mining purposes.

I referred to Weka's web site. (http://weka.wikispaces.com/Databases)

In order to connect Weka and a DB, what I've done are...

**1)Download JDBC Driver for MySQL (mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar)**

**2)Set CLASSPATH as "C:\Program Files\Weka-3-7\mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar" for the user's environmental variable**

**3)Open the RunWeka.ini file and changed the last line into "cp=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Program Files\Weka-3-7\mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar"
(I referred to "http://blog.ahughes.org/?p=347")**

However, Weka 3.7 still produces the No suitable driver error. I tried it by using Weka 3.6, but in vain.

The Weka's web site above seems to provide a little old information, and some information doesn't seem to be related to Weka 3.6 or above.

I would appreciate if you would give any insight.

---

***EDIT***

([WEKA & MySQL Setup a connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441163/weka-mysql-setup-a-connection))
This person seems to have encountered an identical issue, but following the answer of this page didn't solve my issue...

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your "DatabaseUtils.props" in your home directory?

I had the same problem with sql database, I used JDBC-ODBC bridge and it worked, look if you can do the same with Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Troubleshooting section](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Databases#Configuration%20files) of the database configuration there are 3 possible errors that can give you the 'No suitable driver exception'.

1. Your JDBC driver is not set in the CLASSPATH. Finding out if this is the issue can be accomplished by executing the command 'java weka.core.SystemInfo' via the SimpleCLI. If the property 'java.class.path' has only the entry './weka.jar' then you can simply set the CLASSPATH environmental variable to ".;C:/*PATH_TO_JDBC*.jar". Rerun the above command and in the 'java.class.path' you should see now 'java.class.path: ./weka.jar;.;C:/*PATH_TO_JDBC*.jar'
2. The jdbcDriver property is either mispelled or you have used it multiple times in the DatabaseUtils.props (it must be unique)
3. The jdbcURL property is either mispelled or you have used it multiple times in the DatabaseUtils.props (it must be unique)

A final note: if you are using Weka (>= 3.7.2) then you must place the DatabaseUtils.props file under the 'C:\Users\*USERNAME*\wekafiles\props'

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error when using the Weka Explorer GUI.
I double checked:

1. jdbc driver is included in the CLASSPATH used for executing weka
2. Use the correct DatabaseUtil.prop file. In my case I used the sqlite version, renamed it (removed the sqlite from its end), and placed it in ~/wekafiles/props then edited its database address to point to my database
3. After opening weka, make sure the database address is the same as the one in the prop file
4. After cleaning connect, before clicking OK, I had to add a SQL query in the text field. **This one did it for me.** Without the query, pressing OK would result in a false error that said No suitable driver found for [nothing], even though the driver address was absolutely correct.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I did is: add the mysql-connector.jar in existing JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/ folder and restart Weka. BTW, I'm using Weka-3-8-2 and this method works 100%. 
One more thing, do not forget to assign proper URL and Driver for your database connection in DatabaseUtils.props [to be saved in a location having RW permissions to current system user].

Answer (score 0):

After executing the above statement, be sure to map the attribute types in the same `DatabaseUnits.props` file, because Java does not relate the MySQL data type to Weka.

```
# specific data types
#  string, getString() = 0;    --> nominal
#  boolean, getBoolean() = 1;  --> nominal
#  double, getDouble() = 2;    --> numeric
#  byte, getByte() = 3;       --> numeric
#  short, getByte()= 4;        --> numeric
#  int, getInteger() = 5;       --> numeric 
#  long, getLong() = 6;        --> numeric
#  float, getFloat() = 7;      --> numeric
#  date, getDate() = 8;        --> date
#  text, getString() = 9;     --> string
#  time, getTime() = 10;       --> date
#  timestamp, getTime() = 11;  --> date

INT=0    
CHAR=0    
VARCHAR=0    
DOUBLE_PRECISION=2
```

etc...

Good jobs