# Cannot connect to MySQL with Weka

Tags: mysql, weka

I am trying to connect a database to Weka 3.6.13 in **Linux Elementary OS**.

First, I had a problem with JDBC connection, solved by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44088766/6474503) changing the `/usr/bin/weka` file.

Now, when I load the database, this error comes:

`Unknown data type: INT. Add entry in weka/experiment/DatabaseUtils.props.`

However, I am trying to use explorer only, this file doesn't even exists in my installation.

I installed via `sudo apt install weka`.

What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look inside the directory where your `weka.jar` file resides, and check if there exists a file called [DatabaseUtils.props](https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=Databaseutils.props).

The [Weka wiki](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Databases) says:

> Weka *only* looks for the DatabaseUtils.props file. If you take one of
>   the example files listed above, you need to rename it first.

My file is different I think the actual name does not really matter, it's the filename extension that matters.

In my version of this file there is a section that looks like this:

```
... (snip...
# mysql-conversion / type-mappings
CHAR=0
TEXT=0
VARCHAR=0
STRING=0
LONGVARCHAR=9
BINARY=0
VARBINARY=0
LONGVARBINARY=9
BIT=1
BOOL=1
NUMERIC=2
DECIMAL=2
FLOAT=2
DOUBLE=2
TINYINT=3
SMALLINT=4
#SHORT=4
SHORT=5
INTEGER=5
INT=5
BIGINT=6
LONG=6
REAL=7
DATE=8
TIME=10
TIMESTAMP=11

#mappings for table creation
CREATE_STRING=TEXT
CREATE_INT=INT
CREATE_DOUBLE=DOUBLE
CREATE_DATE=DATETIME
DateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

#database flags
checkUpperCaseNames=false
checkLowerCaseNames=false
checkForTable=true
setAutoCommit=true
createIndex=false

# All the reserved keywords for this database
Keywords=\
  AND,\
  ASC,\
  BY,\
  DESC,\
  FROM,\
  GROUP,\
  INSERT,\
  ORDER,\
  SELECT,\
  UPDATE,\
  WHERE

# The character to append to attribute names to avoid exceptions due to
# clashes between keywords and attribute names
KeywordsMaskChar=_

#flags for loading and saving instances using DatabaseLoader/Saver
nominalToStringLimit=50
idColumn=auto_generated_id
```

If you do a [google search for this file](https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=Databaseutils.props), another guy has posted his on [github](https://github.com/bnjmn/weka/blob/master/weka/src/main/java/weka/experiment/DatabaseUtils.props.mysql). The weka Wiki or SVN/Git-Repo might also list an offfical version somewhere (cannot find it right now), or you can open your weka.jar file as a zip file and extract the .props file (/src/main/java/weka/experiment/DatabaseUtils.props.mysql).

In any case, Mysql exists in many different versions, and I think you can even switch the query engine inside mysql. So I cannot express any guarantees that any of these 2 .props files shown here really work for you. You should experiment a bit.

Comment: As I said, I've installed with `apt-get`. Where should this file be?

Comment: Extract it with `unzip  weka.jar weka/experiment/DatabaseUtils.props.mysql` and rename it; or find the Weka public github repo, and download the file from there using the subdirectory I've mentioned.

Comment: So you're saying this feature is only available with `jar` portable installations and not with `apt-get`?

Comment: No. I'm not saying that. If you had `apt-file` installed you could do `apt-file list weka` to see the filelist, what's inside the package that `apt-get` installs. `apt-file list weka | grep jar` shows you where the jar file is located on your computer. On my Ubuntu 16.04 it's here: `/usr/share/java/weka-3.6.13.jar` but I also use newwer versions in custom locations.